# How to WPF Slider and Textbox two way binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox, slider

i want  `slider` value to binding on `textbox` and `textbox` to  `slider`  value(user interaction).
im now just `textbox` binded of `slider` value.  How can i get it?

```
<TextBox 
Width="70" 
Height="20" 
Grid.Row="1" 
Margin="0 0 80 180" 
x:Name="AO1text"               
Text="{Binding ElementName=AOch1,Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:F2}}"/>
```

```
<Slider 
x:Name="AOch1" 
Maximum="20" 
Minimum="4" 
Value="{Binding ao1value}" 
Width="250" 
BorderThickness="5" 
TickPlacement="BottomRight"
```

Comment: Do you have a ViewModel? Then you can bind both to the same property in the ViewModel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```xml
<TextBox Width="120" Text="{Binding ElementName=AOch1, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:N0}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<Slider x:Name="AOch1" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Width="250" />
```

```csharp
// Get value from Slider
targetObject.Value = AOch1.Value;
```

The recommended approach is:

1. Create a class with property, like Value

```csharp
public class ItemModel 
{ 
    double _Value = 4;

    public double Value
    {
        get => _Value;
        set
        {
            if (value < 4)
                value = 4;

            if (value > 20)
                value = 20;

            if (_Value != value)
            {
                _Value = value;
                // Notify Property Changed
            }
        }
    }
}

// Window1.xaml.cs
ItemModel model = new ItemModel();

// Window1_Loaded
yourGrid.DataContext = model;
```

2. Bind ItemModel.Value to the TextBox.Text and Slider.Value.

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:F2}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<Slider Value="{Binding Path=Value}" Maximum="20" Minimum="4" Width="250" BorderThickness="5" TickPlacement="BottomRight" />
```

3. In this way, in the code section, you only need to access ItemModel.Value.

Comment: Thank you. i`ll try this soon. but i have question. Is there any way to handle it in Viewmodel?